# neo4jrb - Save ActiveRel property from node

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, neo4j.rb

I have a ActiveNode like this:

```
class Nodeexample
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  property :name

  validates :name, :presence => true

  has_many :in, :nodeexamples, rel_class: :SomeRel

end
```

and a ActiveRel model like this:

```
class SomeRel
  include Neo4j::ActiveRel

  property :some_number, type: Float

  from_class :Nodeexample
  to_class :Nodeexample

  type :SOME_REL
  validates :some_number, :presence => true

end
```

I'm trying to figure out how to add the "some_number" property in the ActiveRel model:

```
node1 = Nodeexample.new(name:"node1")
node2 = Nodeexample.new(name:"node2")

#how can I add the "some_number" property in the ActiveRel class from here?
node1.nodes << node2

node1.save
```

The only way I know is by saving the two nodes first and them save the relationship, but i want to save all at once, is it possible? It's strange save 100 nodes and then save 500 relationships :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with the `create` method:

```
node1 = Nodeexample.new(name:"node1")
node2 = Nodeexample.new(name:"node2")

node1.nodes.create(node2, some_number: 123)
```

There shouldn't be a need for `node1.save` when using either `<<` or `create`